# Angular JS http interceptor async call infinite loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angular-http-interceptors

Hello I try to make a async call in the response method of a http interceptor in AngularJS. The async call gets fired but then gets stuck in an infinite loop and the async call gets called over and over... Not sure why, I guess the error has to do with the structure of my async call

```
var app = angular.module('AceAngularApi', []);
```

app.service('Ace',['$http','$q','$injector', '$window', function($http, $q, $injector, $window){

```
this.user = null;

var setToken = function(token){
    $window.localStorage.token = token;
};

var removeToken = function(){
    $window.localStorage.token = '';
}

var setCurrentUser = function(currentUser){
    user = currentUser;
};

var getCurrentUser = function(){
    var self = this;
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/api/currentuser";

    var response = $http.post(url, {}).then(function(response){
        if(response.data.data["obj"]){
            self.user = response.data.data["obj"];
        }

        return response;
    });

    return response;
};

var currentUser = function(){
    return user;
};

return {
    setToken: setToken,
    setCurrentUser: setCurrentUser,
    getCurrentUser: getCurrentUser,
    currentUser: this.user,
    removeToken: removeToken
  }

  }]);


app.factory('authInterceptor',['$rootScope', '$q', '$window', '$injector', 
function ($rootScope, $q, $window, $injector) {
return {
request: function (config) {
  config.headers = config.headers || {};
  if ($window.localStorage.token) {
    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $window.localStorage.token;
  }
  return config;
},
response: function(response) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var Ace = $injector.get('Ace');
    Ace.getCurrentUser().then(function(){
        deferred.resolve(response);
    });

    return deferred.promise;    
    }
   };
   }]);

 app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add a check in your `Ace` service so that `getCurrentUser` is only making one async call, regardless of how many times it is called.

```
var callStatus = false;
var getCurrentUser = function() {
    var self = this;
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/api/currentuser";

    if(!callStatus) {
        callStatus = $http.post(url, {}).then(function(response){

        if(response.data.data["obj"]){
            self.user = response.data.data["obj"];
        }});
    }

    return callStatus;
};
```